# Adding Ubuntu Boot entry to Fedora 33 Grub2 with separate /boot partition

Tags: ubuntu, boot, fedora, grub

I installed Ubuntu using `debootstrap` and `chroot` into the below partitions,

```
├─nvme0n1p4                                   259:4    0   2.3G  0 part  /run/media/ignor/a62e0718-10c6-4224-8097-3a3f6c780070/boot
└─nvme0n1p5                                   259:5    0  52.2G  0 part  
  └─luks-03d97a82-4ec5-4824-8fc3-a3b5eb38d4f9 253:1    0  52.2G  0 crypt /run/media/ignor/a62e0718-10c6-4224-8097-3a3f6c780070
```

I tried to add this ubuntu partition with Grub2 but mimicking the existing entries,

```
[root@localhost boot]# cat /boot/loader/entries/c4c41f9ff04f4b2ab6b1e1667737970d-5.11.12-200.fc33.x86_64.conf 
title Fedora (5.11.12-200.fc33.x86_64) 33 (Workstation Edition)
version 5.11.12-200.fc33.x86_64
linux /vmlinuz-5.11.12-200.fc33.x86_64
initrd /initramfs-5.11.12-200.fc33.x86_64.img
options root=UUID=3b76b920-f5f8-40a9-b6f1-c16d3e6e5c9a ro rd.luks.uuid=luks-e5359785-6f0f-4d59-a3a3-1a6a4828e5fc rhgb quiet 
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class kernel
```

And created this Ubuntu entry, but I am using a separate `/boot` partition for Ubuntu.

```
[root@localhost boot]# cat /boot/loader/entries/ubuntu-5.8.0-49-generic.conf 
title Ubuntu (5.8.0-49-generic)
version 5.8.0-49-generic
linux /vmlinuz-5.8.0-49-generic
initrd /initrd.img-5.8.0-49-generic
options root=UUID=a62e0718-10c6-4224-8097-3a3f6c780070 ro rd.luks.uuid=luks-03d97a82-4ec5-4824-8fc3-a3b5eb38d4f9 rhgb quiet 
grub_users $grub_users
grub_arg --unrestricted
grub_class kernel
```

How do I get it to use the kernel in the ubuntu `/boot/` partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom grub entries into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and then reconfigure grub with this entry by running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`